# How to Send Bep-20 Token to Multiple addresses without using for loop in web3 or Ethers

Tags: node.js, angularjs, blockchain, web3js, ethers.js

We want to send tokens to multiple addreses without using any loop and also we did'nt wrote the solidity. If im using loop site getting very slow and also it throw timeout error. Is There any possiable to solve this.

We want code node or angular js

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disperse contract? It does help you to send tokens to multiple wallets.

Try interacting with them in [web3client.app](https://workspace.web3client.app/evm?web3ClientToken=50f4540e-e813-48a0-8cac-e2bd762a86ea).